# What's a word or phrase to describe something that quite literally assimilates from its surrounding

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm trying to talk about fashion as art/science. What could a be good word/phrase to say it's omnipresent and you see it everywhere around you.

(i want to mention how fashion accommodates every vocation, that as an industry you will find it around you in some shape or form eg. trends forecasting, visual merchandising, big data collecting user information)

Sample sentences: Like many, I thought of it as insubstantial; as its stereotypical preceding reputation of being frivolous or vain. But fashion ***draws/absorbs/assimilates*** from life around it. The clothes we wear on our backs carry stories from around the world.

Comment: What do you mean: fashion **accommodates** every vocation? Everywhere around you where? In the street? In the media?

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I meant everywhere quite literally, in the media, street, office or art.

Comment: @KillingTime sorry I'm new to this. I want to use the concept of the word several times. I just edited a sample sentence.

Comment: _draws heavily on_, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you want “fashion is ***ubiquitous***”  (That’s from the question in your first paragraph. It doesn’t fit your sample sentence though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reflects**

> [reflect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reflect) verb (SHOW)
> B2 [ T ]
> to show, express, or be a sign of something:

Fashion reflects life around it.

You could also say that fashion trends are a reflection of life. (For example: Sweat pants and leggins are now office-wear- it was heading that way but the pandemic sped it up. The fashion trend is a reflection of peoples' needs and priorities after a year in quarantine.)

A quick search of "fashion reflects society" found many examples, such as [HISTORY IN FABRIC: FASHION’S REFLECTIONS OF SOCIETY](https://www.crfashionbook.com/fashion/a32950305/fashion-society-trends-economy-protest/):

> The clothes we wear are not only one of the truest forms of self expression, but also a reflection of the world in which we exist.

Comment: Yes, this is a likely interpretation. accommodate was inaccurately used.

Comment: @Lambie YEs, I think this answer covers the third paragraph in the OP. The middle paragraph- about accommodates- seems to be more about fashion being all encompassing in life- how the fashion industry studies people, etc. Still, all that study leads to it reflecting society. Ultimately their goal is to sell clothes.

Answer (score 1):

Going off this part of your question:

> What could a be good word/phrase to say it's omnipresent and you see it everywhere around you.

- extensive: having a wide scope, effect, influence, etc.; far-reaching; comprehensive
- osmosis: 2. A gradual, often unconscious process of assimilation or absorption, e.g. "learned French by osmosis while residing in Paris for 15 years."
- interleave: to arrange in or as if in alternate layers
- quotidian: found in the ordinary course of events; everyday, ordinary

> "...fashion as extensively / osmotically interleaved with quotidian
> life..."